# How do I publicly Tweet a reply to another person?

Tags: twitter

It's best described by an example:

1. Twitter @A tweets:  "I am a rabbit"
2. Twitter @B replies: "@A how sad it is"

The goal is to make the Tweet from @B to public so every follower of @B would see even if they are not following @A. Normally @B would Tweet like this:

> ".@A how sad it is"

(note the dot).

Otherwise only those who follow both @A and @B would see that reply.

It would be just like a Re-Tweet but your own Tweet.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

These tweets are always public. Anyone can see them anytime. But Twitter website is not built to show @B's replies to @A on the home timeline if they are not following @A. But there are Twitter clients that does it. I remember TweetDeck having this feature. It'd show the followers of @B all of his tweets and replies to @A even if they are not following @A.

Comment: Do you know does TweetDeck support this now?

Comment: No, I don't use Tweetdeck. Just install the software and check the settings.